# Unable to understand the Connectivity

Tags: c#, sql, linq, ado.net, linq-to-xml

I am learning C# and I want to access a database.  I have been searching pages on .net database connectivity for the last two - three days.  I also came to know that it has several ways for the connectivity and this is exactly where my mind started to ask a number of questions.  Please tell me if I am wrong in my understanding.

Check out this [Diagram 1](http://sdrv.ms/LVWa7H).

Now what I am getting here are five ways of connectivity:

1. Linq to Objects
2. Linq to Datasets
3. Linq to SQL
4. Linq to Entities
5. Linq to XML

Here is another [Diagram 2](http://sdrv.ms/LVWfrX) of ADO.net Architecture -

I have read the definitions, but am not able to differentiate the functionality and purposes.  Can anyone give me a short explanation of both diagrams for my understanding?

1. **Suppose I am a programmer who write code in C#; which way should I

   prefer to write desktop based has database connectivity that 
   has future?**
2. **To Software Developer is it needed to go through all the
   preceding ways of data access from database?**

Comment: Entity Framework is recommended ORM library for new .NET Framework Applications. It uses LINQ to Entities to perform queries.

Comment: Please upload images, instead of linking to obscure URLs.

Comment: Sir, i am unable to upload images due to limitation of Reputation. I have recently joined Stackoverflow and the URL will take you to my Microsoft Skydrive shared files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the answer to number 1, use [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) and a database. The database could be relational (like [SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/default.aspx)), or document-based (like [MongoDb](http://www.mongodb.org/)). If you just grab the free [Visual Studio 2013 express](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx) and start by creating a new project from a template, you'll probably end up with some version of SQL Server to start out with.

You have a lot of options for Linq to Whatever because sometimes you just have to get data out of repository and if you can use Linq as a facade to it, then getting your data out is that much easier because it feels a lot like getting data out of a database. There's even [Linq to Twitter](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/). For a brand new project though, you'll most likely use a database.

For the answer to number 2, you would only do that on an existing application that you are maintaining. It is fine technology, but if you're creating a new project, use Entity Framework.

Comment: So Sir, Linq is used to fetch data in ReadOnly manner from Database?

Answer (score 1):

Under the covers of all the data libraries, every time you access the database three things happen:
 - a connection is made to the database
 - a command is created (to select, update, insert or delete data)
 - the command is executed in the database

In the case of LINQ or EF, the SQL for the command is generated automatically from your objects, but ultimately, the same three actions happen.

If you want to understand the basics, start with the ADO.NET objects. If you want to get something running more quickly take a look at EF, or nHibernate.